# Change default photo picker intent text?

Tags: java, android, share-intent

**Photo picker intent:**

```
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

The text, shown below, currently says "Complete action using Photos". Is there a way to change this to something custom?

[image]

Comment: "The text, shown below, currently says "Complete action using photos"" -- no, it has "Complete action using Photos", with a capital P. That's the name of an app. Had you most recently used "Meme Generator Free", it would have "Complete action using Meme Generator Free".

Comment: Thanks. It's an important distinction. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple. The answer is No. Also in won't always be "with Photos", it will depend on most used(or recent) app for this kind of Action.

### Lil update

You can use some other way of doing this.

```
Intent.createChooser(yourIntent, "Open via ..." /*your text goes here*/)
```

This will look differently, but will have your text

Use like this

```
 this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail via ..."));
```

Comment: Sounds good! Yes that does seem to be related to the Google Photos app, what with the icon. I suppose the design solution would involve some kind of alert dialog indicating a profile picture change prior to launching this....